# Number of digits in report string

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

My report needs to count the number of digits in the destination value. National calls have more than 10 digits, local calls have less than 10, and international calls have exactly 10. How can I sort these different call types into different sections?

[image]

Comment: you can convert your Destination to string and then count the number of characters: myDestination.ToString().Length

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new formula to use as the basis of a group. Inside the formula, use this code:

```
If Length(CSTR({yourTable.destination})) < 10 
Then "Local"  
Else If Length(CSTR({yourTable.destination})) > 10
Then "National"
Else "International"
```

Then add a new group with this new formula as the determination.